# How can I copy the lower triangle into the upper triangle?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a matrix in Google Drive Spreadsheets. Only the lower triangle is filled. I would like to copy the values of the lower triangle to the upper triangle. How can I achieve that?

Example:

Initial matrix:

[image]

Objective:

[image]

Spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aoy6Mj_UZoTEdDA1emRsQ2F0cU13RG9HVDF5MlBFYnc&usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from link in original post :

[image: WA58768 example]

C2 formula: `=INDEX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,$A2+1)&":"&ADDRESS(10,$A2+1)),MATCH(C$1,$A$2:$A$10,0))`